# parsing an XML in Python

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml data like .

```
<rentals type="array">
  <rental>
    <account-id type="integer">130</account-id>
    <created-at type="datetime">2011-08-26T23:27:13Z</created-at>
    <description>1 - 1 br apt, walk-up - </description>
    <id type="integer">218</id>
    <name>Apt.1</name>
    <notes nil="true"/>
    <position type="integer">1</position>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2011-12-06T09:00:58Z</updated-at>
  </rental>
  <rental>
    <account-id type="integer">130</account-id>
    <created-at type="datetime">2011-08-22T03:06:49Z</created-at>
    <description>2 - Alcove Studio, walk-up, remote 3</description>
    <id type="integer">210</id>
    <name>Apt.2</name>
    <notes nil="true"/>
    <position type="integer">2</position>
    <updated-at type="datetime">2012-09-26T21:37:20Z</updated-at>
  </rental>

</rentals>
```

I used the [Pyxml2obj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyxml2obj/) python library to parse this into the python dict .Using XMLin

I go the response like .

```
{u'rental': {u'Apt.19': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'19 - big, spot lights studio', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-11T18:03:24Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2013-01-19T02:07:02Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'11', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'1303', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.20': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'20 - same as 19', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-14T23:19:58Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2013-01-19T02:07:23Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'12', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'1304', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.8': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'8 - studio, walk-up', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-08T13:18:07Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-08-27T01:25:36Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'5', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'222', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.10': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'10 - semi luxury studio, elevator', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-08T13:40:52Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-09-01T15:02:21Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'6', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'226', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.7': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'7 - studio, remote', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-07T20:40:58Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-08-27T01:25:00Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'4', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'221', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.5': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'5 - huge studio', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-07T19:24:30Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-08-27T01:23:56Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'3', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'219', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.2': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'2 - Alcove Studio, walk-up, remote 3', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2012-09-26T21:37:20Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-08-22T03:06:49Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'2', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'210', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.15': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'15 - alcove, walk-up', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-14T22:39:41Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-11-04T20:13:49Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'9', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'344', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.16': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'16 - Studio', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-09T23:12:45Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-11-29T06:12:33Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'10', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'378', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.1': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'1 - 1 br apt, walk-up - ', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2011-12-06T09:00:58Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-08-26T23:27:13Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'1', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'218', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.25': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'studio with back yard', u'notes': {}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-14T20:32:07Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2013-04-01T13:02:59Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'17', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'2683', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.24': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'24 - studio', u'notes': {}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-12T16:18:23Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2013-03-22T21:15:29Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'16', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'1910', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.23': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'23 - alcove studio', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-15T01:01:13Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2013-02-02T19:06:33Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'15', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'1351', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.11': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'11 - Split Studio, remote', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-11T20:02:19Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-10-07T14:55:38Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'7', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'308', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.21': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'21 - walk up, alcove studio', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-14T06:05:49Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2013-02-02T19:05:03Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'13', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'1349', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.22': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'22 - 1br big', u'notes': {u'nil': u'true'}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-10T13:45:47Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2013-02-02T19:06:08Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'14', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'1350', u'type': u'integer'}}, u'Apt.14': {u'account-id': {'content': u'130', u'type': u'integer'}, u'description': u'14 - 1 BR walk-up', u'notes': {}, u'updated-at': {'content': u'2013-04-12T17:31:31Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'created-at': {'content': u'2011-11-01T03:37:15Z', u'type': u'datetime'}, u'position': {'content': u'8', u'type': u'integer'}, u'id': {'content': u'339', u'type': u'integer'}}}, u'type': u'array'}
```

Now I am trying to iterate over this dict to get the individual data like ,

```
for rentall in getdictobj.items():
    rentall.name
```

I am getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I know that object has no  attributes name but In the Xml name is clearly mentioned .

Please help me to figure what might I am doing wrong here

Comment: you missed colsing tags for the last rental

Comment: that one is my writing error since xml is too big

Comment: How you are getting the keys Apt.19 , content in the response file? These keys are not available as nodes in XML. Can you try with xml.dom.minidom parser it will be easy for you to parse and fetch all the name nodes.

Comment: @kvivek  the xml data is very large so have posted only two rentals from the top if you want I can post that also

Answer (score 0):

Dict.items returns a list of tuples (name . Value ) where the name is the dict index , and can be anything that is not a mutable object. You should say for name, value in .....

Example:

```
 for i, value in d.items():
   print i, value
```

Or, you can convert the dict to tuple or list so:

```
T = tuple (d.items())
T = list (d.items())
```

and now you can can iterate over a tuple/list instead of a dict.

Comment: please elaborate some more

Comment: `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` then `for k, v in d.items()` will have the letters (keys) in `k` and the numbers (values) in `v` in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternate way to get all the name nodes.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse(r'C:\Users\kvivek\Desktop\rentals.xml')
nameNodes = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('name')
for nameNode in nameNodes:
    print namenode.toxml()
```